# Listview style issue when changing the page

Tags: jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I'm working on a single page application using jquery mobile along with knockout.js binding on MVC4 platform..

This is my button on the main div page:

```
<div data-role="page" id="pageMain">
 <div data-role="content">
    <a href="#" id="btnExisting" data-bind="click: $root.GetHeader"   data-role="button"   data-theme="b"">View Invoices</a>
 </div> 
</div>
```

This is my target div page:

```
<div data-role="page" id="pageExisting">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Existing Invoices's</h1>
        <a data-rel="back" data-role="button">Back</a>
    </div>
    <div class="choice_list" data-role="content" data-bind="visible: Headers().length > 0">

        <ul id="headersList" data-role="listview" data-bind="foreach: Headers" data-filter-placeholder="Search Invoice" data-filter-theme="a" data-inset="true"
            data-filter="true" data-theme="b">

            <li>

                <a href="#" data-inline="true">

                    <h2>Invoice No.: <span data-bind="text: inv_no"></span></h2>

                    <p>Amount.: <span data-bind="text: inv_amt"></span></p>
                </a>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the script section:

```
var HeaderViewModel = function () {
        //Make the self as 'this' reference
        var self = this;
     self.Headers = ko.observableArray([]);
function GetHeaders() {
        //Ajax Call Get All Employee Records
        // self.GetHeaders = function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/api/InvAPI",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                self.Headers(data); 


            },
            complete: function () {
                $.mobile.changePage("#pageExisting");

            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error.status + "<--and--> " + error.statusText);
            }
        });

    }
self.GetHeader = function () {
        GetHeaders();
    }
   };


$(document).ready(function () {
 ko.applyBindings(new HeaderViewModel());
}
```

When I hit the button "view Invoices" I get a typical Jquery mobile formated listview
but the problem is when I hit the back button and navigate again to the "PageExisiting" div Page I get the list data with no styling..

When viewing page source in both cases, I noticed that on second navigation;
Li tags have not attributes.

I have tried some solutions like: listview refresh, page destroy, page create prior to the line:

```
$.mobile.changePage("#pageExisting");
```

with no luck.

I'm stuck here guys and I will appreciate your proposed solutions

Thanks

Comment: Where did you try listview refresh?

Comment: @Omar I tried it before the line:$.mobile.changePage("#pageExisting");

Comment: Try this. `$('document').on('pageshow', '#pageID', function () { $('[data-role=listview]').listview('refresh'); });` or `pagebeforeshow`. Try both

Comment: @Omar I tried them both.. Same result

Comment: Are you getting any error when you refresh the list? If you force refresh (f5) does the list get styled? And btw, add the code I gave you before separately, don't add it within your function.

Comment: @Omar I don't get any error and I have already tried the code separately.

Comment: @Omar Yes On the main page, when I refresh(F5) and hit the button the list get styled.. Sorry, I forgot to mention that in the question

Comment: I just saw `.ready()` it's not recommended to use it, use `.on('pageinit', function()` or any other events I.e. pagebeforeshow .. Etc

Comment: @Omar when I put the ko.applybindings code inside a page init or show beforeshow; the pageExisting did not open at all

Comment: Doesn't show at all or listview only?

Comment: @Omar Just relocated the line of ko binding right after the HeaderViewModel declaration and it worked

Comment: @Omar Thank you very much for help, you may want to post the solution instead of a comment .on pagebeforeshow worked, pageshow also worked but you see the list not styled for a moment in this case. so pagebeforeshow is the one:)

Comment: @Omar so please post your solution as an answer and I will mark it solved. Thank you

Comment: So you bind your function to pagebeforeshow?

Comment: @Omar Nope, I bind my function before pagebeforeshow then I put the line:  $("#headersList").listview("refresh"); inside the pagebeforeshow

Comment: I'm glad you got it solved Adel :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refresh list view before showing the page.

```
$('#pageID').on('pagebeforeshow', function() {
 $('[data-role=listview]').listview('refresh');
});
```